# Évolution de l'ordre et du sens de "trop" : chronologie et origine ?

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie, argot

Dans les années 90/2000, j'ai personnellement noté en France un nouvel usage populaire de l'adverbe "trop" avec les caractéristiques suivantes :

**Perte de la notion d'excès, qui différencie normalement *trop* de *très***

> Ce mec il est trop beau (avec le sens de *très beau*, pas comme dans *trop beau pour elle* où on retrouve la notion d'excès)

**Tendance parfois à placer loin en avant de l'adjectif (en début de phrase, ou avant un article)**

> Trop elle est bonne cette meuf (alors que la construction grammaticale normale serait "elle est trop bonne")

**Usage sans adjectif, pour qualifier une phrase, avec un sens similaire à *vraiment***

> Trop il m'a vénèr (= vraiment, il m'a énervé)
>
> C'est trop un connard ce type (= vraiment)
>
> J'ai trop plein de thune (= j'ai vraiment beaucoup d'argent)

**Usage qualifiant *pas***

> J'ai trop pas envie (= je n'ai vraiment pas envie)

À ne pas confondre avec la tournure suivant qui est plus ancienne

> J'ai pas trop envie (= je n'ai que moyennement envie)

**Usage seul, pour répondre par l'affirmative**

> — Tu kiffes ?
>
> — Trop ! (ou, pour la négative, *trop pas !*)

**Usage parfois associé à *mais* et/ou des pauses et/ou une prosodie plus élevée, le tout pour une emphase additionnelle**

> C'est mais - trop - bon ce truc (les tirets représentant des pauses, le *trop* étant prononcé sur une tonalité relativement aiguë).

Questions :

1. Quelqu'un d'autre peut-il attester cet usage et qu'il s'agit d'un glissement par rapport aux usages plus anciens de *trop* ? Sur le Tlfi, l'usage qui s'en rapproche peut-être le plus est "*être trop*" (*les gens trouvent que je suis trop*), mais ce n'est pas pareil.
2. Quelle est la date approximative de ce glissement ?
3. Quelle est son origine ? Influence d'une langue étrangère, par exemple un calque ? Évolution interne au français, par exemple une "inflation emphatique" poussant à l'usage de mots de plus en plus extrêmes pour porter l'emphase ?

Comment: Manifestement c'est de la nov-langue. C'est vrai qu'il sert à toutes les sauces "trop" maintenant. Autre exemple de "trop" se suffisant à lui-même : "A : Elle est chère cette caisse !" "B : Trop !" (dans le sens "Carrément !" ou "Trop vrai !" plus que dans un sens d'emphase ou d'excès).

Comment: La perte de la notion d'excès me semble très naturelle. Cela fait au moins plusieurs décennies qu'à vouloir mettre l'emphase sur un mot, on fini par le modifier : bon, très bon, super bon, hyper bon, trop bon... D'ailleurs il me semble qu'on utilise le plus souvent ces néologismes pour décrire des émotions qui, comme le reste, subissent une inflation

Comment: @SteffX merci j'ai ajouté "inflation emphatique" comme hypothèse

Comment: Je l'atteste aussi. Je suis d'accord pour l'hypothèse d'évolution naturelle. On le trouve aussi en anglais : "Oh my God, too funny."

Comment: Ce n'est pas le premier glissement sémantique et fonctionnel de ce mot qui de substantif germanique (**thorp*, **throp*, village) à donné, via le latin vulgaire, deux substantifs français (troupe et troupeau) et un adverbe (trop) qui devient subrepticement un adjectif...

Comment: @Julien merci, j'ai ajouté l'usage solo de "Trop" et "Trop pas" dans la question

Comment: Merci, merci, merci de dénoncer l'usage de ce "trop" envahissant. Mais personne ne semble répondre à votre question. Depuis quand est utilisé ce "trop bon" ? En regardant les films on voit apparaître l'expression depuis le début des années 2000.

Answer (score 2):

Je (Qc., sud-ouest) reconnais plusieurs des emplois et les particularités énoncées, mais pas l'antéposition (*Trop elle est bonne cette meuf.*) ni l'emploi comme *vraiment* en début de phrase (*Trop il m'a vénèr.*) ; je peux comprendre une variante où l'on appuie fortement sur *trop* en inversant le verbe de l'exemple (*Mais c'est... trop... bon*.) mais je trouve plus usuel d'appuyer sur « trop bon » et non sur *trop* uniquement.

---

*Au lexique.* Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/trop) dit parle de l'« Empl. adj., fam. [Sur le modèle de l'angl. [*too much*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/too-much?s=t), dans le lang. des jeunes] » puis on a sous cette rubrique 1. *être trop* dont vous avez traité et 2. *c'est trop !*, dans le sens de c'est *extraordinaire*, *formidable*. L'exagération, l'hyperbole etc. Mais on a aussi des valeurs de superlatif comme synonyme de *très, fort*, dans des formules de politesse (*trop aimable*), avec des tours hypocoristiques (*trop mignon*) ou dans des phrases exprimant une appréciation subjective comme « Ah! non c'est trop drôle! Ah! ah! ah! » (Feydeau) ou « Ah! c'est trop con! » (Sartre). Je ne vois pas en quoi les emplois en question ne participeraient des emplois au lexique. Par ailleurs je n'ai pas d'expertise pour affirmer quoi que ce soit avec certitude ; on pense que se produit aussi peut-être plus généralement entre *trop* et *très* le même genre de [phénomènes](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3425) qu'avec *excessivement/extrêmement* (le premier employé parfois couramment pour *très*) ; et que le modèle de l'anglais concoure au ou avec (le) phénomène. On ne sait pas depuis [quand](https://www.etymonline.com/word/too), de mémoire assurément depuis plusieurs décennies voire plus d'un siècle dans le cas de l'emploi du type de l'[exemple](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Dame_de_chez_Maxim) de Feydeau...

Comment: Merci, on peut donc au moins dire qu'il s'agit d'un régionalisme français...

Comment: *trop* dans ce sens peut s'utiliser avec des mots qui ne sont pas d'argot mais le registre est populaire

Comment: quant au lexique il ne s'agit ni d'une formule de politesse, ni d'un tour hypocoristique... peut-être est-il cependant proche du "trop drôle" de Feydeau ou du "trop con" de Sartre, mais détaché de la nécessité de se rapporter à un adjectif et pouvant se rapporter à n'importe quel élément de la phrase, comme *vraiment* au fond

Comment: Je suis familier avec le deux tours que vous avez ajoutés (_j'ai trop pas envie_, et _trop (pas)_ seul). Merci !